# Highcharts: Creating gantt chart having stacked rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am creating a gantt chart using Highcharts for a process that has three phase Request, Submission and Approval. It has two stacks for Planned and Actual.
I used the highcharts stacked bars to represent the data plotted like this [jsFiddle of Gantt](http://jsfiddle.net/mudBorn/VCRTx/1/) 

Instead of data as

```
           series: [{
            name: 'Requested',
            data: [1,3,4,5,6],
            stack: 'Planned'
        }, {
            name: 'Requested',
            data: [2,4,5,7,8],
            stack: 'Actual'
        }, {
            name: 'Submitted',
            data: [2,3,2,3,4],
            stack: 'Planned'
        }, {
            name: 'Submitted',
            data: [3,5,2,3,4],
            stack: 'Actual'
        }, {
            name: 'Approved',
            data: [6,3,2,3,4],
            stack: 'Planned'
        }, {
            name: 'Approved',
            data: [2,4,2,3,4],
            stack: 'Actual'
        }]
```

I want the data as dates here I have the first,second and third dates respectively for Requested,Submission and Approval.

```
 series: [{
            name: 'Part1',
            data: [Date.UTC(2013,01,12),Date.UTC(2013,01,23),Date.UTC(2013,02,05)],
            stack: 'Planned'
        }, {
            name: 'Part1',
            data: [Date.UTC(2013,01,15),Date.UTC(2013,01,29),Date.UTC(2013,02,05)],
            stack: 'Actual'
        },]
```

I need the series name on y-axis to be taken from the data in series

```
 xAxis: {
               categories: ['Part1', 'Part2', 'Part3', 'Part4', 'Part5']             
            },
```

and
1. the start should be from the data[0] instead hence it will contain two bars and three points.
2. I need difference of dates in the bar so hence I can show the time for each activity.

I tried a with time in milliseconds[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mudBorn/pxdb9/) but couldn't come to anything substantial

Comment: It's a little unclear for me what is wrong with first example, and what is wrong with second one, could you update question with this? Also, have you seen gantt example from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r6emu/1934/).

Comment: @PawełFus the first example is right but I need that 1. the zero for indiviual bar should start from 1st value.2. the values must be dates 3. bars should represent the difference in dates i.e. number of days to complete the task.

Comment: With simple stacking bars first point is not possible. Use or solution from my first comment, or try to use column-range chart with inverted options for a chart. 2) It's not a problem, use datetime axis. 3) You need to preprocess data for that and use difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "low" and "y" properties in the data so an X offset is rendered and therefore you can have the "Gantt effect" you need:

Please check this example:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'bar'
},

title: {
    text: 'Gantt module development plan'  
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Using fake data'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['Planning', 'Development', 'Testing', 'Documentation']
},

yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    min: Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1)
},

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                 console.log(this.point);
                var point = this.point;
                return '<b>'+ point.category +'</b><br/>'+
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e, %Y', point.low) + ' - ' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e, %Y', point.y);
            } 
        },

series: [{
    data: [{
        low: Date.UTC(2011, 11, 20),
        y: Date.UTC(2012, 0, 15)
    }, {
        low: Date.UTC(2012, 0, 10),
        y: Date.UTC(2012, 4, 28)
    }, {
        low: Date.UTC(2012, 3, 15),
        y: Date.UTC(2012, 4, 28)
    }, {
        low: Date.UTC(2012, 4, 15),
        y: Date.UTC(2012, 4, 28)
    }]
}]

});
```

Cheers

Fran